# Simulink: List programmatically the connections between subsystems

Tags: matlab, connection, simulink

I have a Simulink model that includes a lot of inter-connected subsystems. A lot of these subsystems are connected to the other with "goto" objects. For verification and documentation purpose, I need to get the complete list of inputs/outputs of each sub-system, and check that the subsystem are connected between them as expected. Checking manually each connection is really time consuming and I often make mistakes doing it. Is there a way (function/script/command) to obtain the list automatically? Thank you very much if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have you considered using the Simulink Model Advisor to do this? You can [create your own custom checks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/slvnv/create-checks.html).

Secondly, it is possible to determine which blocks a sub-system (or any other block is connected to)

Selecting a block manually in the model and then running the following, will give you a cell array of all the blocks that the current block is connected to.

```
connected_to = get_param(gcb,'PortConnectivity')
```

If the block has 4 inputs, then the `connected_to` variable will contain 4 items. You can get the Source Block name by doing

```
srcBlockName = connected_to(1).SrcBlock;
```

Typically you would work from the outports back through the model to the inports or other source blocks checking what is connected to each.